# Insulating and soundproofing a bedroom floor

Tags: insulation, sound-deadening

I'm looking to insulate a first floor bedroom in my house (in Ireland). I currently have pine flooring (which makes an awful noise when we step on it) and looking underneath these I see that there's no insulation at all. I'm hopeful of tearing up the floor, putting insulation between the joists, and then screwing down chipboard or OSB with a view to getting some sort of flooring or carpeting.

I'm very new to DIY, so I'm wondering if there's anything else I should be thinking of while doing this. Unknown unknown as it were. Is the above approach a good one, any types of insulation needed, do I need to worry about moisture of some sort, ventilation etc? Any suggestions would be greatly received.

The climate here is generally quite damp, but the house itself has good ventilation. There's no mildew or anything of the kind.

Comment: More info about your climate, type of construction, materials available to you, ( I never use chip board or OSB in the US, for subflooring.)  Do you have axcess to under the floor?  Basement or crawl space?  More info for better answers please.

Comment: Chip board would be inappropriate for a subfloor in the US (here you'll find it in subfloors from the 70s and 80s). As underlayment between the subfloor and the floor's surface material, though, I guess it could be okay. OSB is the cheap option in the US, where 3/4" is available in tongue and groove so you don't get soft spots at seams. Even with OSB subfloors you'll often see plywood used in bathrooms for its dimensional stability when it gets wet.

Comment: Apologies for the (very) delayed follow up folks. I've added in some extra detail to the initial question. To access the joists I'd have to tear up the floor and I'm able to see the plasterboard of the ceiling below. No insulation or anything.

Comment: You haven't characterized the noise you're trying to minimize.  Is it sound transmission of the actual footstep thuds to the area below, are you hearing squeaks of nails/fasteners not holding the floorboards tight to the floor joists, or some other noise from the floors as you step on them (such as creaking wood as it flexes, etc.)?  The solutions to the different sources of noise are quite different.

Comment: Agree 100% with @Milwrdfan. The way to solve noise issues depends on the kind of noises you're getting. If it's just the thud of foot falls, some insulation may help. If it's squeaking, simply screwing down the existing flooring better may be the way to go.

Comment: It's two things really. Firstly can hear a conversation clearly in our bedroom from the kitchen below, we'd definitely like to minimise that. Secondly we also have creaking pine floors upstairs. I can hear someone walking around in the adjacent bedroom. If I can sort those out, or at least minimise the noise that would be great.